# Filtered data refreshes to unfiltered data when clicking next page of web forms GridView

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a web forms project that has one filter. When the user filters the data and clicks on the next page, the filter seems to get taken off and the default data is displayed. How can I fix this? Is it the OnPageIndexChanging attribute method that needs updating? I've shown the code behind below for the ONPageIndexChanging method and the method used to bind the data (had to cut some out to get rid of the "too much code" error but if I'm missing anything that would be helpful, please let me know.)

```
   protected void dashboard_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        dashboard.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        BindDataToGridView();
    }

    void BindDataToGridView(SqlCommand cmdSQL = null)
    {
        // default sql
        if (cmdSQL is null)
        {
            cmdSQL = new
                SqlCommand("SELECT TabID, TabName, Title, CreatedOnDate, TabPath From [tableName].[dbo].[Tabs] Order By TabName");
        }
        var connectionFromConfig = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ConnectionString;
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionFromConfig);
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            DataTable rst = new DataTable();
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            dashboard.DataSource = rst;
            dashboard.DataBind();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of your BindDataToGridView() for the paging event?

Call the SAME routine you have for the button click to filter the dates.

(you could even pull out the code for the button click into a separate routine. That routine filters by date, so have both your button click to filter, and the page index change event call that same routine.

So, for paging, you have to call the routine with the filter. This kind of suggests that you want one routine to load the grid, and it has to figure out if you have a filter or not. So, you might check for start/end date being blank. this would allow both page load event, the filter button, and the data page change event ALL to call ONE common routine.

So, a few things:

If you going to bind a grid/list view? and page? And filter?

(3 issues)?

Then make ONE common routine for all to call.

Say like this:

```
    void BindDataToGridView()
    {
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("");

        cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT TabID, TabName, Title, CreatedOnDate, TabPath From TableName Order By TabName";

        if (startDate.Text != "")
        {
            // filter
            cmdSQL.CommandText = 
                "SELECT TabID, TabName, Title, CreatedOnDate, TabPath From TableName " +
                "WERE CreatedOnDate >= @Start AND <= @End ORDER By TabName";

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startDate.Text;
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.Date).Value = endDate.Text;
        }
        using (cmdSQL)
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            DataTable rst = new DataTable();
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            dashboard.DataSource = rst;
            dashboard.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

So now we are NOT passing the filter. You could I suppose also put the sql or the status of the filter into view state, and have the filter routine check this, but you better off to do the above.

In fact, I often suggest that we filter the reocrdset against its built in "view", as that can save database hits, but it don't matter.

So, when introducing filters? AND paging? You have to keep the above in mind.

So, now we have one routine for page load, the button click and the pager changing index code.